# Can I combine more than one call to a method after the => operator?

Tags: c#

I am using this method to set and get properties:

```
bool _selectEnabled;
public bool SelectEnabled
{
   get => _selectEnabled;
   set => SetProperty(ref _selectEnabled, value);
}
```

and:

```
protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(
     ref T backingStore, T value,
     [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
     Action onChanged = null)
{
   if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
      return false;

      backingStore = value;
      onChanged?.Invoke();
      OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
      return true;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") 
      => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

This works well but I have the case sometimes where I need to do more than just set and get. For example here:

```
bool _selectEnabled;
public bool SelectEnabled {
    get { return _selectEnabled; }
    set { if (value != _selectEnabled) {
        _selectEnabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectEnabled");
        // I need to call a method after the set. The methods
        // will be different for each property.
        myMethod("ABC", _selectEnabled);
       }
    }
 }
```

Is it possible for me to call the another method something like this:

```
bool _selectEnabled;
public bool SelectEnabled
{
    get => _selectEnabled;
    set => { SetProperty(ref _selectEnabled, value);
                myMethod("ABC", _selectEnabled); }
}
```

I know this way won't work but is there a way that I can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way; but only because your example shows some code which needs to be called if the value of the property has changed (i.e. it is not called unconditionally).

The `SetProperty` method declaration that you've shown has a `onChanged` parameter which is an Action that is only invoked if the value has changed. So you could write:

```
set => SetProperty(ref _selectEnabled, value,
    onChanged: () => myMethod("ABC", _selectEnabled));
```

You *could* also extend the method to allow you to supply unconditional code in a similar way; but I'd say that's a bad idea (it's a slippery slope). If you're looking for unconditional execution, go with Camilo's answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but is the syntax correct? When I code this it tells me that the { after set => is "an invalid expression term"

Comment: Apologies. Serves me right for answering from my device. Answer edited, please try again.

Answer (score 4):

No, the [arrow operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) (also known as fat arrow), when used for expression-bodied members, is for expressions, which can be seen as single statements. So, if you want to execute two statements, you cannot use them.

Just do it as you would have done before c# 6:

```
bool _selectEnabled;
public bool SelectEnabled
{
    get => _selectEnabled;
    set
    { 
        SetProperty(ref _selectEnabled, value);
        myMethod("ABC", _selectEnabled); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your opening statement isn't quite true. As the link you put says `=>` can be used to define a lambda expressions or expression body definition. The latter is what we are looking at here and is indeed a single expression. The lambda operator can be used for statement lambdas as shown on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/lambda-expressions which can have multiple statements in a syntax similar to what the OP was hoping for.

Comment: @Chris I wouldn't say it wasn't true, I would say it was incomplete. I modified the statement to clarify that, thanks!

Comment: I mainly wanted it clarified because many people aren't aware that you can do multi statement lambda and I don't want to reinforce that idea. :)

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "lambda operator" at all. There's nothing lambda-related about it. This is just an expression-bodied member. The C# team tend to use the term "fat arrow" to talk about the syntax that's used for both lambda expressions and expression-bodied members.

Comment: @DaisyShipton It's normally called the *arrow operator*, but lambda operator is the official name if you look at the documentation's URL

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: When it's used for a lambda expression, sure. But that's not how it's being used here. Look at the two bullets at the start of the page - the first of them talks about the lambda operator, in the context of lambda expressions. The second bullet talks about `=>` being used for expression-bodied members. The part within "The lambda operator" is a bit overly general, I admit - but I think it's highly confusing to conflate the two. Note how the word "lambda" doesn't appear anywhere within the section on expression bodied members.

Comment: As another example of it being used not for lambda expressions, see the [May 5th LDM notes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/9e05ecfd9f2a46314120484dc4a0d91faf741bbb/meetings/2018/LDM-2018-05-02.md), where the same syntax is considered for switch/case: "Looks like a lambda but isn't one". The syntax and the meaning aren't synonymous. (I don't consider those docs to be the definitive source, btw - I'd consider the C# spec to be definitive here. The term "lambda operator" doesn't occur anywhere in the csharplang repo, according to github search.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yeah, I get what you mean. See my update and feel free to improve the wording :)

Comment: Well, I'd just remove the "lambda operator" but from the brackets, personally :) Definitely better as "arrow operator" than "lambda operator", although I wouldn't consider it to be an operator at all. It's just part of the syntax for declaring a member. But I'm not going to argue any further about that :)